# Linux - Discovering a process run in the past

Tags: linux, process, process-management

Suppose that a random process I don’t know its TID,PID and name but I know it starts at time X and ends at time X + 5 seconds... Is there a way to discover the TID, PID, and name of process for instance at time X+6 seconds? I would like to get the same informations given by ps

Answer (score 0):

The information is not recorded, unless process accounting is enabled, see [man 5 acct](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/acct.5.html).

If you enable accounting before the process in question terminates, then you can get the information from the accounting file as explained on the man page.